# How to Center h5 with ul

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My footer has the next code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5><u><i>Informacion</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li><a href="#">Acerca de Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contactanos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trabaja con Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prensa</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5><u><i>Social</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/fb.jpg" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/twitter.png" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/Linkedin.png" alt="FB" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

With definition of CSS style in html for testing. The problem is coming I can´t achieve h5 center text agaisnt ul. If I use text-align in h5 it works just for the first ul (supposing for the length of a´s Text).

[image: It works with Text Align:Center]
[image: Not working with Text-Align:center]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove inline style `style="list-style-type: none;"` from ul and add bootstrap class `list-unstyled` to reset default ul style i.e `margin, padding` and than put `text-center` class to parent element to make all child center.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5><u><i>Informacion</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Acerca de Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contactanos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trabaja con Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prensa</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h5><u><i>Social</i></u></h5><br />
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/fb.jpg" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/twitter.png" alt="FB" /></a></li><br />
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="imgFooter" src="~/Content/img/Social/Linkedin.png" alt="FB" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://www.bootply.com/XZebLWPP4D)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe center text in both children?

```
.pull-right h5,
.pull-right ul{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The final Style is not the desired. Each li has different length and they are not align.